# How to solve post request ddos

Tags: ddos, apache2

Today our magento shop is under attack, I am hoping someone can help tell me how to block these requests from 100's of different IPs:

```
182.255.44.234 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:14 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
59.61.38.24 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:14 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
120.39.95.47 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:13 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
114.236.17.181 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:14 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
114.236.17.181 - - [15/May/2017:13:23:47 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
58.219.222.251 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:15 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
182.46.161.100 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:16 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
49.83.89.244 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:16 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
117.28.127.48 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:16 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
60.167.222.175 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:16 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
114.236.17.181 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:16 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
110.84.8.132 - - [15/May/2017:13:24:17 +0100] "POST /calais-shop/customer/account/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 503 1916
```

I cannot block POST requests so I am wondering what is the best solution?

Rob

Answer (score 2):

This was a top Google result for searching "magento createPost attack" so I'll go ahead and include my solution here.

**DISCLAIMER** you should never modify Magento Core. Since you might be panicking during an ongoing attack like this, you might **temporarily** modify the Magento Core files and implement a **proper solution** once you have banned the offending IPs.

*tl;dr*  move application code from that URL (`/route/being/attacked`) to another (`/some/new/route`), update front-end code to submit form (or whatever) to `/some/new/route`, log all IP addresses visiting `/route/being/attacked` and ban them with IPtables or your tool of choice.

What you're doing here is creating a honeypot to catch the offending IP's so that you can permanently ban them via your preferred means e.g., iptables.

1. Relocate functionality from Mage_Customer_AccountController::createPostAction

   Simply create a new method in the AccountController e.g., `createPostNewAction` which is a copy/paste of the contents of `createPostAction`
2. Update frontend form URL's to new route

   The route to /customer/account/createPost is retrieved from a Helper class, `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::getRegisterPostUrl`. You should modify this method so that it returns the route to your new action e.g., `return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/createpostnew');`
3. Log offendings IPs in `createPostAction`

   Replace the contents of `createPostAction` with a logging statement. Ensure this logfile is not overwritten or automatically truncated if you wish.

   ```
   public function createPostAction {
      Mage::log($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'ban_customer_spam_ips', true);
      return false;
   }
   ```

So now what we've done is moved the functionality to handle the 'new customer registration form' to a new route, and replaced the original route with a logging statement that will log the IP address of whomever requested the URL to the file `ban_customer_spam_ips`. There is no reason for a legitimate request to hit this route, so we can assume that any requests to this route are malicious and we can ban them.

As the root user, `tail` the aforementioned logfile and ban IP's using whatever method you prefer. Here I'm using `fail2ban` which leverages `iptables`. You might choose to use `iptables` directly-- do whatever you prefer. Adjust paths as needed, my Magento installation is `/var/www/magento` but yours may be different! You can create a `.sh` file and execute that in the background, or just run this on command line:

```
tail -f /var/www/magento/var/log/ban_customer_spam_ips | awk '
BEGIN {}
{
    print "banning ip: " $4

    block_command = "fail2ban-client set apache banip "$4
    system(block_command)
    close(block_command)
}'
```